# GAE with Laravel / Lumen extremely slow

Tags: php, google-app-engine, laravel-5, lumen

I have a server hosted on DigitalOcean responding within 70-300ms window depending on the request. The same code when hosted on GAE external or local server response time goes up 3 times even when I put `dd('test')` in `index.php` file. It's clear GAE PHP interpreter is extremely slow. Did anyone experience this problem and fixed it?

What I found out is it takes longer for GAE to boot laravel or even lumen than it takes my 5$ DigitalOcean server to respond! It's ridiculously slow.

Comment: Hm, comparing **boot time** on a **PaaS** infra (failing to detail its flavour/config, but that's another story) with **request response time** on **IaaS** infra?

Comment: @DanCornilescu I understand it's not going to be as fast but for it to be 3 times slower is something I weren't expecting.

Comment: Can you give App Engine Flexible a shot, and see if that's any better?  The new model is probably going to be a fair bit faster....  https://cloud.google.com/php/getting-started/hello-world

Comment: @JustinBeckwith I can't try it as it's in development. I prefer to wait until it is stable. Thank you for the information, I will keep an eye on this and try it once it's stable enough for production environment. Now I just decided to move to AngularJS to hide long response times as much as possible not to make users frustrated by long loading times.